# Python Train Test Split

Tags: python, train-test-split

Below is the code and below that is the error.

```
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
X-train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.2,random_state=0)
```

Error:

```
runfile('C:/Users/HP/Desktop/Python/P14-Machine-Learning-AZ-Template-Folder/Machine Learning A-Z Template Folder/Part 1 - Data Preprocessing/data_preprocessing_template.py', wdir='C:/Users/HP/Desktop/Python/P14-Machine-Learning-AZ-Template-Folder/Machine Learning A-Z Template Folder/Part 1 - Data Preprocessing')
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "C:\Users\HP\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py", line 3326, in run_code
    exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)

  File "<ipython-input-44-136d41c04781>", line 1, in <module>
    runfile('C:/Users/HP/Desktop/Python/P14-Machine-Learning-AZ-Template-Folder/Machine Learning A-Z Template Folder/Part 1 - Data Preprocessing/data_preprocessing_template.py', wdir='C:/Users/HP/Desktop/Python/P14-Machine-Learning-AZ-Template-Folder/Machine Learning A-Z Template Folder/Part 1 - Data Preprocessing')

  File "C:\Users\HP\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder_kernels\customize\spydercustomize.py", line 827, in runfile
    execfile(filename, namespace)

  File "C:\Users\HP\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder_kernels\customize\spydercustomize.py", line 110, in execfile
    exec(compile(f.read(), filename, 'exec'), namespace)

  File "C:/Users/HP/Desktop/Python/P14-Machine-Learning-AZ-Template-Folder/Machine Learning A-Z Template Folder/Part 1 - Data Preprocessing/data_preprocessing_template.py", line 35
    X-train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.2,random_state=0)
                                                                                           ^
SyntaxError: can't assign to operator
```

Comment: Why are you using X-train ? Shouldn't it be X_train ?

Comment: Please add a description of your case, the problem, your tried solutions and the resolving you search for

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that you are trying to a assign to a variable with a dash (-) at the var name.
In python, variables name cannot have dashes. Python relates them as arithmetic operators.

Change your code from:

```py
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
X-train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.2,random_state=0)
```

To

```py
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.2,random_state=0)
```

Answer (score 0):

Read https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#prescriptive-naming-conventions. Dashes must not be used while naming a Python variable. While naming, only alphanumeric and underscore characters can be used. Change your code from

```
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
X-train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.2,random_state=0)
```

to

```
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.2,random_state=0)
```

This will resolve your issue.